# NFT metadata (.MP4)

Tags: metaplex, metadata

I'm looking to deploy MP4 NFTs and I already have the 0.json/0.mp4 files.

I'm just wondering how I would go about with the metadata. The metaplex metadata requires you to have an `image` field.

I'm not sure what to put in the 'image'.
Can I have all three files 0.json, 0.mp4 and 0.png in the assets folder when deploying?

This is how my metadata looks like for my 0.mp4. Does this seem correct? I'm putting the MP4 file name in the `files` and `animation_url` keys. I'm also putting the 0.png in the `image` key

```
  "name": "Test Key #1",
  "symbol": "TK",
  "description": "These are just test keys.",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
  "image": "0.png",
  "external_url": "https://test.xyz",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "type",
      "value": "test"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "0.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "uri": "0.mp4",
        "type": "video/mp4"
      }
    ],
    "category": "video"
  },
  "animation_url": "0.mp4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the token metadata standard you should always have an image field present in the off chain metadata. This field is used as fallback for wallets, websites etc. that are unable to render your video file.

From my point of view the metadata you  presented above looks correct.